# generating reference id after form submit

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop

I am trying to generate a reference id like this `CTS-P 0 then CTS-P 1` each time a user submits a form and it gets inserted.

what i have came up with is inserting `CTS-P 0` to database as i submit.but the problem is its not incrementing `CTS-P 0 to CTS-P 1` after i submit again.

i tried to use `mysql_insert_id()`  here is what i have done so far.this is the smallest thing but i could not solve. please have a look

```
    <?php 
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("dbname",$con);
$genid="";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {   
$frstname=$_POST["frstname"];   

$genid=mysql_insert_id();
$genid .=count($genid);
//echo $genid;

for($i=0; $i<$genid; $i++) {

$sql = "INSERT INTO tblname (`namecol`,`refidcol`) VALUES ('$frstname','CTS-P $genid[$i]')";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
}}
    ?>

//here is the form
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="generate" >

First Name<input type="text"  name="frstname" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

it is inserting it in my refid column as CTS-P 0 but not incrementing from next time i submit.i know its very noobish but i am stuck.

Comment: You've read that `mysql_*` functions are obsolete and that `mysql_insert_id()` works only with `auto_increment` columns, right?

Comment: no i dont know if it only works with AI only and its obsolete.so any other way to approach?

Comment: you can fetch the last record from db and then can add +1 to this like
$rec=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query(slect max(id) from tablename));
$form_id='CTS-P'.$rec['id']+1;
then use this at the time of insert query

Comment: What @manojdhiman said is exactly what you **never want or should do** because that just destroys data integrity and removes concurrency from the play. You want to have an auto_increment column. You just want to insert your `$firstname`. When you PULL the data out, you just add `CTS-P` before the generated auto_incremented number. Voila, problem solved forever, without any black magic.

Comment: what do you mean??? @ N.B ??

Comment: @manojdhiman - I mean what I wrote. If you require further explanation, you have to look into what concurrency and data integrity are, what auto_increment does and why you should never "generate" any sort of unique references in PHP. What you suggested works when only 1 person uses the system. When more than 1 person uses it, your solution produces clashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
    $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("dbname",$con);

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {   
        $frstname=$_POST["frstname"];   

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblname";
        $genid = mysql_query($sql, $con);
        $genid = mysql_num_rows($genid);

        //Since you're using "0" as your first number, I decided to comment this out, if not, uncomment it
        //$genid++;

        $sql = "INSERT INTO tblname (`namecol`,`refidcol`) VALUES ('$frstname','CTS-P $genid')";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Can you tell me what errors it returned? UPDATE: I've edited the script, missed the actual query part. This SHOULD work in theory.